# SQL Server connection error when trying to import from another DB on server

Tags: sql-server, connection

SQL Server 2014 Express is installed on a VM Windows Server 2016. There are several databases attached and when trying to import a table from one DB into another on the same server, I got the following error message:

> Login timeout expired
> A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
> SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].  (Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0)

I can log onto SQL Server and run queries as per normal which includes joining tables from different databases but just can't export/import data within SQL Server using the import/export data wizard.

I have double checked that the server name is spelt correctly.

The export/import wizard has been working fine until about a week ago and there have not been any changes made to the configuration.

When trying to troubleshoot I tried to find the SQL Server Browser service in the SQL Server configuration manager was unable to. Not sure if this is relevant there is also SQL Server 2016 installed on the same VM and I do not see the SQL Server Browser server for this either but the Export/Import Wizard runs OK between the various databases on SQL Server 2016

Many thanks

Comment: "Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections." - permissions or wrong name, or firewall, remote connections not enabled....  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: the instance name is correct and SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/sbs/topic/solving-connectivity-errors-to-sql-server-ae23c94b-b64b-5056-8b62-22e1694bb889

Comment: Have you looked in SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Services > SQL Server Browser yet? You need to restart the Browser service after any change to an SQL Server's network configuration, or instance name, as this is the only time that the Browser service detects the new information. Of course if you use Port Numbers in your connection strings (instead of Instance Names) then the SQL Server Browser service is completely redundant.